# Adobe Flex: vertical alignment of labels in a Form control

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, forms, label, alignment

Like shown in the following picture I've got a form in my application.
There are 3 FormItems, of which two contains a ComboBox and one a HGroup with a ComboBox and an Image.
In the last FormItem the label isn't centered vertically.

The difference between FormItem 2-3 (in the pic red) is 18px.
The difference between FormItem 1-2 (in the pic green) is 22px.

I assume this is because of the HGroup but I don't know how to solve this problem.
Any hints?

The code is:

```
<mx:Form>
  <mx:FormItem id="type" label="xxx:">
    <s:ComboBox />
  </mx:FormItem>
  <mx:FormItem label="xxx:">
    <s:ComboBox />
  </mx:FormItem>
  <mx:FormItem label="xxx:">
    <s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle"
              height="25">
        <s:ComboBox />
        <mx:Image source="@Embed(source='assets/icons/info_xsmall.png')" />
    </s:HGroup>
  </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

[image: problem]

Comment: Could you post the code please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot :) I added the code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the HGroup?  Instead try using the "direction" property of FormItem and setting it to "horizontal".  So your code would now be:

```
<mx:Form>
  <mx:FormItem id="type" label="xxx:">
    <s:ComboBox />
  </mx:FormItem>
  <mx:FormItem label="xxx:">
    <s:ComboBox />
  </mx:FormItem>
  <mx:FormItem label="xxx:" direction="horizontal">
        <s:ComboBox />
        <mx:Image source="@Embed(source='assets/icons/info_xsmall.png')" />
  </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

Comment: Should have added that using the above technique should ensure that your labels are vertically aligned.

Comment: When you do that you can't center vertically the elements inside the FormItem. If someone has the same problem, a solution is to set the elements' height to the same fixed value. (Flex3 still lives)